# JAVA: Querying data in range of two Timestamps

Tags: java, mongodb, timestamp

im currently trying to get data from MongoDB, where a Timestamp-field is used in the query for filtering.
I have this function where i would like to get a list of my saved Entities between two timestamps. The Result is always 0.

Why don't I get any Data?

Java: 12 
MongoDB: 4.2.0 Community

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;


Timestamp from = Timestamp.valueOf("2015-03-15 00:30:54.160");
Timestamp to = Timestamp.valueOf("2019-11-15 08:00:00.000");

public List<?> getAllLogsFromXToY(Timestamp from, Timestamp to) {

        FindIterable<Document> result
        = getCollection(entity).find(
            and(
                gte("creationDate",from),
                lte("creationDate", to)));

        return parseQueryResult(result, <clazzObj>);
    }
```

```
MongoDB Data: 

{
  "_id": "5DCE6CF965D6D0067F4065A7",
  "RECORDS": [
    {
      "newValue": "\\töüwläuq\\",
      "object_type": "de.hfu.revhiso.files.MongoFile",
      "log_category": "ENTITY_OPERATION",
      "description": "changed field filePath",
      "TX_ID__id": "5DCE6CF965D6D0067F4065A7",
      "oldValue": "\\",
      "entity_id": "5DCD6CF6E3420915ABE67B56",
      "modified_date": "6758113787372371968",
      "object_attribute": "filePath",
      "classicication": "USER_OPERATIONS"
    }
  ],
  "USER_ID__id": "5DCD6CD9E3420915ABE5FC2A",
  "creationDate": "6758113787372371968",
  "MODIFIED_USER__id": "5DCD6CD9E3420915ABE5FC2A"
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_log_transactions")
@NoSql(dataFormat = DataFormatType.MAPPED)
public class LogTransaction  extends RevhisoEntity  {

    @ManyToOne
    @Field(name = "account_id")
    protected User user_id;  // Ausführende

    @ManyToOne
    @Field(name = "modified_user_id")
    protected User modified_user; //Auftraggeber

    @ElementCollection
    private List<LogRecord> records = new Vector<LogRecord>();

    @Basic
    @Field(name = "creationDate")
    @Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    protected java.util.Date creationDate;
```

EDIT: I used  JPA(eclipseLink) to  insert the Data. I added the entity in the post

Comment: Please show a sample of what the data looks like in the `from`, `to` _and_ the `time` fields.

Comment: I added it in the post

Comment: The `creationDate` has a string value. What does it contain? How is it to be interpreted as a timestamp or a date?

Comment: To compare date / timestamp fields, both the field values must be same type (in this case `creationDate` and the `from, to`).

Comment: They should  be  the same Type.  The insert operation  was done by eclipseLink.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer why it wasnt showing any results... the Timestamp was saved as a number or string as prasad_ said.
The Problem know is, that Eclipselink is parsing the Date the wrong Way.

SOLUTION FOR INITIAL PROBLEM:

```
using LocalDateTime for the Date.
```